# Upload server log into aws cloudwatch log using cloudwatch log agent in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, log, aws

aws support Centralized logs for server , we can send custom logs to cloudwatch logs mu awslogs.conf file code is

```
datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
file = /path/to/log/file/test.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = test
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = server1
```

It creates a log file in aws cloudwatch log named test in server1 group

But my custom log file name is current date for example 
filename = test-2018-03-15.log

I tried the following code

```
datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
file = /path/to/log/file/test-%Y-%m-%d.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = test-%Y
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = server1
```

It doesn't work

and also i tried in file path
   file = /path/to/log/file/test-{%Y-%m-%d}.log

it also doesn't work

How to upload log files which have current date in their filename to aws cloudwatch using cloudwatch log agent

Comment: You can use `file = /path/to/log/file/test-*.log`. Only the most recent file will be uploaded, according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html).

Comment: @Jos  daily log files created automatically with current date as a file name , `file = /path/to/log/file/test-*.log` it will point all files with `test-date.log` , I need to point current date only not yesterday

Comment: Only the current file will be pushed to Cloudwatch, based on modification time, as it says in the user guide.

Comment: then how to create log stream with current date  `file = path/to/log/file/test-$(date +%Y).log` is not working

Comment: `file = /path/to/log/file/test-*.log` its working fine thanks @Jos